# PHP Function: Split csv field value into name and lastname

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV column of authors, for example:

Jhon Appleseed.

The fields of author have name and last name, I want it to split on the ImportCSVaction.php file that import the CSV. Actually the function only gets all the value of the cell and insert it on the lastname, doesn't split it into Name and Last Name.

The function is:

```
private function processBookAuthors($book, $authorArray) {
    //ControllerBase::getLogger()->info("Start.");
    $bookAuthors = [];
    foreach (explode($this->multipleValuesDelimiter,
                     $authorArray["lastName"]) as $authorName) {
        if (!ValidationHelper::isEmpty($authorName)) {
            $author = new Author();
            $author->setLastName($authorName);

            if (!isset($this->authors[$authorName])) {
                $this->authors[$authorName] = $author;
            }

            $bookAuthors[] = $this->authors[$authorName];
        }
    }
    $book->setAuthors($bookAuthors);

    //ControllerBase::getLogger()->info("End.");
    return true;
}
```

I tried modifying the CSV file and using the value:

Jhon, Appleseed
Appleseed, Jhon
John; Appleseed

But didn't work, I see I need to modify the PHP import function.

Comment: What is the value of $this->multipleValuesDelimiter ?

Comment: How does the first row of the csv file look like? And how does your $authorArray look like?